# run ffprobe via shell_exec on php give no output but the main command itself

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec, ffprobe

executing ffprobe command from php ( on windows host ) give no output any idea how to fix this ?

```
$batexec = ("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\nginx\\nginx\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -show_format rtmp://example.com/live/live");

shell_exec($batexec);

echo $batexec;
```

Answer (score 1):

While using `ffprobe` you have to indicate the path to the .exe file without repeating the ffprobe part, for example in you case you should use

```
$result = shell_exec("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\nginx\\nginx\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -show_format rtmp://example.com/live/live");

print("result :: $result");
```

with the sample you have you are passing `ffprobe` as an argument to `ffprobe.exe`

Comment: it comes back empty no result

Comment: your example is working i just had to add \\ to the ffprobe.exe path and now it's working so edit your answer to approve it

Comment: what is the output of this
**
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\nginx\nginx\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe
**

Comment: no output if the path is with only one backslash. your code is correct if you add double backslash